# Where can I find info for how to create a Coin/Token?

Tags: solidity, tokens, altcoin

I'm planning on creating a new Coin/Token. Most probably a Token.

I know there are some repositories on GitHub to create tokens based on ERC20. And there is also platforms like CointTool.app to create very easy one token. Like also some tutorials on YouTube or blogs that teach you how. But none digs deep in how to set for the different types.

Has anyone got any experience building tokens? Or, do you know where I could find any group that talk's about creating coins or tokens?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is a *transactional token*?

Comment: After atlkikng with some developers these types are not accurate. Will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get many tutorials over youtube, google, and even in ethereum official website: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/understand-the-erc-20-token-smart-contract/

openzeppeline is also a good way to save time and build tokens fast, but it will not make your basics clear, and you will not be able to make some new kind of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have come across [Openzeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc20-supply)